# Spring Best solution for API with Long processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

im working on spring boot project where i have to expose an API that trigger a long processing that takes more than 5 minutes. this is my API :

```
 @GetMapping("/print")
  public ResponseEntity<String> print() {

    // Call External API One to get data & process
    // Call External API Two to get data & process
    // Call External API Tree get data & process
    // Call internal Service to Update database
    
    // this API takes more than 5min
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Ok..", HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

this endpoint will be called by a batch and we don't want to make this batch waiting a long time for the response from this endpoint and also avoid time out issues.

do you have any idea about the best practise and the paradigm tha i can implement to develop this API ?

thanks

Comment: Are the APIs 1,2, and 3 related (dependent)? Like is there any requirement like something from API-1 that needs to be used in API-2 or 3?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran thanks for your question. the APIs are not related

Comment: Respond with an (http) `accepted` and an url, where client can poll/track underlying response/process... ;)

Comment: So @James, will there be any issues in making them `Asynchronous`

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic scenario for async service. The basic idea is that when you have a long-running task you just acknowledge to the client, that request has been received and return some task id as part of your acknowledgment response. Using this id client will know what to look for when the result arrives. Meanwhile, the server performs the task and writes the result to some channel mutually agreed upon with the client—usually a queue, sometimes DB. The client listens to that channel and when a message with the id gets there client reads it. That way the client doesn't have to wait online for the entire processing time.

Answer (score 1):

If you aim to redesign an API (not implementation) in such a way, that no API methods executes for a long time, then there are two common approaches:

**1. Split API method to "start execution" (POST) and "check result" (GET)**

First method should start execution in a background and return a generated identifier assigned to the call. It could be `UUID.randomUUID()` or incremented counter, for example. In case of counter make sure of thread safety, consider `AtomicLong`. To perform the execution background using `ThreadPool`/`Executors` and obtaining `Future` is the most common choice.

Second method takes identifier as a parameter, checks whether calculation is complete and return either "not yet completed" signal or calculated response. As a "not completed" signal you could use, for example, `204 No Content` HTTP code.

To implement that approach you have to keep track of executed background calculations and ids assigned to them. Be careful and store <id, Future> map in a thread-safe way. Don't forget to remove old entries after some time and/or after retrieval. Obviously, that solution works with single server instance only.

**2. Pass a callback url as a parameter**

Used rarely. You can pass an URL as a parameter, return from method immediately and POST calculated data to saved URL after calculation would be complete.

Also, you can probably significantly boost your implementation by calling API 1, 2 and 3 in a parallel as they are not related. Consider using `WebClient` which is asynchronous and doesn't require dedicated thread for each call.